# How to add records in postgeSQL by pgAdmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I created table in pgAdmin4:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Aktor"(            --tableWithActors
        "ID" bigint[] NOT NULL,         --id
        "Imie" "char"[] NOT NULL,       --name
        "Nazwisko" "char"[] NOT NULL,   --surname
        "DataUrodzenia" date,           --dateOfBirth
        "Wzrost" integer,               --height
        CONSTRAINT "Aktor_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

And now I'm using on this table option: Scripts>INSERT Script to insert data into the table

```
INSERT INTO public."Aktor"(
         "Imie", "Nazwisko", "DataUrodzenia", "Wzrost")
VALUES ('Sylvester', 'Stallone', '1946-07-16', '177');
```

When I do execute, system returns:

```
ERROR: BŁĄD: nieprawidłowy literał tablicy: "Sylvester" LINE 3: VALUES ('Sylvester', 'Stallone', '1946-07-16', '177'); ^ DETAIL: Wartość tablicy musi zaczynać się od "{" lub informacji o wymiarze. 
SQL state: 22P02 
Character: 87
```

[pgAdmin4 error when I insert (SCREENSHOT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWwal.jpg)
How should I write it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared columns to be arrays.  I would also get rid of the escaped names:

```
CREATE TABLE public.Aktor (            --tableWithActors
        ID bigint serial,         --id
        Imie varchar(255) NOT NULL,       --name
        Nazwisko varchar[] NOT NULL,   --surname
        DataUrodzenia date,           --dateOfBirth
        Wzrost integer,               --height
        CONSTRAINT Aktor_pke PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4712989a1f5f571bbab189f2d64d3d49) is a db<>fiddle.

Notes:

- Strings in SQL are not arrays.  They are simply `varchar()`s.
- The `id` should be auto-incremented.  In Postgres, that uses a `serial` type.
- Escaped names are just cumbersome.  Don't use them if you can avoid them.
- There is no need for arrays for this data structure.